# Number of unique integer in random generated arrays

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random

I generated 1.000.000 random integers in the range from 0 to 1.000.000 (`using rand() in c++ and random.randrange() in python`) and both code got approximately 632000 unique numbers.

I noticed $1 - e^{-1} = 0.6321$.

Does $e$ involve in this? If so, why?

```
Unique number | Total numbers in array
632413           1000000

632088           1000000

631594           1000000

6305             10000

6319             10000
```

Comment: I don't think so.
The probability of an event with $p = 1/n$ happen at least 1 time in n trials is (similar to the linked thread): $1-(1-1/n)^n$

But i failed to see the correlation between the number of unique numbers in a randomly generated array
and the probability mentioned above.

Can you show me the similarity?

Comment: I'll post something explaining the connection.

Comment: Additional reading: [Probability of repeatedly selecting object in group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4193473/probability-of-repeatedly-selecting-object-in-group/4193504#4193504) where I additionally show that the number of numbers selected $k$ times was $\frac{1}{e\cdot k!}$ (*note that $0! = 1$*), so the numbers selected zero times occurred with probability $\frac{1}{e}$, once with probability $\frac{1}{e}$, twice with $\frac{1}{2e}$, three times with $\frac{1}{6e}$ etc...

Comment: To emphasize, the behavior you witnessed was not a result of python or programming limitations, but is indeed the expected theoretical result.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1087950/calculating-probability-of-getting-m-unique-numbers-when-choosing-n-times-fr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be a large number (in your case, $N=10^6$).

By linearity of expectation, we define an indicator for each number from $1$ to $N$ according to whether or not it appears.

The probability that a number appears is $$1-\left(\frac {N-1}{N}\right)^{N}$$

Hence your expectation is $$N\left(1-\left(\frac {N-1}{N}\right)^{N}\right)$$

Now, $$\lim_{N\to \infty} \left(\frac {N-1}N\right)^N=1-e^{-1}$$

So your expectation is approximately $$N\times (1-e^{-1})$$ as desired.

Comment: You mean $\frac1e$ in both places you have $e$.

Comment: @saulspatz  Right, thanks.

Comment: @amWhy  I was the one who first voted to close this as a duplicate (indeed, I was the one who answered the duplicate question).  The OP wasn't capable of seeing how the duplicate answered the question, so I agreed to post the specific calculation.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I understand, @lulu.